# Can´t load the "src" of an image via json (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

```js
var topArticle=new Vue({
  el:'#toparticle',
  data:{topmostArticle:null},
  created: function(){
              fetch('topnews.json')
              .then(r=>r.json())
              .then(res=>{this.topmostArticle=$.grep(res,function(e){return e.topnews!==" "});
              console.log(this.topmostArticle);
              });
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>The greatest news app ever</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.3.1/css/foundation.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id  ="toparticle">
      <img src="{{topmostArticle[0].topnews[0].img}}">
      <img src="2.jpg">
      "{{topmostArticle[0].topnews[0].img}}"
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to load the source for an image with an external file but I'm facing some problems...the source isn't recognized in the image tag. The code should be correct because when the data is loaded outside the image tag  it works nice. Anyone has any idea?? Thank you so much!

The first image is not loaded (because the src is transmitted via json), the second is ok and the third command, "{{topmostArticle[0].topnews[0].img}}", returns "2.jpg" so it's ok

JSON

```
           [{"topnews":[
                {"timestamp":"0",
                 "id":"2",
                 "cathegory":"2",
                 "headline":"2",
                 "text":"2",
                 "img":"2.jpg",
                 "url":"2.jpg",
                 "author":"2",
                 "comments":"2"
                },
                {"timestamp":"0",
                 "id":"2",
                 "cathegory":"3",
                 "headline":"3",
                 "text":"3",
                 "img":"3",
                 "url":"3",
                 "author":"3",
                 "comments":"3"
                 }
              ]}]
```

The question is why I can't load the src directly through json?
Please click on the links below(web view) for more clarity!

```
  [web view][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbFeq.png
```

Comment: What language is that? Please add the relevant code to your question, it's hard  to debug images.

Comment: it is in html and javascript...can you please copy the url of the 4 images in your browswer?.... I made some errors while posting

Comment: Nope, you can edit the question. Just copy-paste the relevant code to the post and select the pasted code and click `{}` icon on the editor tools.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to get the image

```
<img :src="require(`@/assets/${topnews.img}`)" alt="Top News" />
```

Comment: "require()" method no longer works for now. It gives an system warning and can't load the local image.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the way that you bind the attribute:

```
<img :src="topmostArticle[0].topnews[0].img">
```

Comment: If you right-click the broken image and inspect it in your browser, what shows up as the src property?

Comment: <img src="{{topmostArticle[0].topnews[0].img}}"> and by hovering: "Couldn't load the image"

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Maybe some browser settings??

Comment: Did you try using :src and no curly braces?

Comment: <img :src="topmostArticle[0].topnews[0].img"> is not working

Comment: I can't help you any further without a full copy of the code either linked to this question or added as a snippet. Until then it's all guesswork.